# XAMPP 1.7.7 in Windows 7 returns nothing using curl

Tags: php, curl, xampp, localhost

I have a problem working with

```
curl_getinfo
```

I have already checked the **php.ini** for *curl extension* and everything seems to be fine and inside **phpinfo();**, *curl* is enable so I know that It shouldn't have any problem.

This function runs fine in my web server. It is my local machine with **XAMPP 1.7.7** that gives me a hard time. Could this be because of firwall settings of my laptop?

Please note that the jpg file exists inside the Amazon s3 URL and I have checked the Amazon URL on the browser and it shows the image...

/////////////////// Edited //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

here is my code which is a function or method inside a class:

```
public function pictureExistence($id){

    $url = AMAZON_S3_URL . $id . '.jpg';

    //var_dump($url);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    //var_dump($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    //var_dump($code);

    if($code == 200){
        $status = true;
    }else{
        $status = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your complete code - ie how you create your resource for `curl_getinfo`

Comment: Do not use these "all-in-one" installers. People who use them end up asking these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code and check whether it's working for you. It has been tested to work fine on **XAMPP 1.7.7** .

```
 <?php
    // Create a curl handle
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');

    // Execute
    curl_exec($ch);

    // Check if any error occured
    if(!curl_errno($ch))
    {
     $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

     echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
    }

    // Close handle
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Comment: that means **curl_getinfo** is working! otherwise it would have thrown some error.

Comment: This works perfectly with XAMPP 1.7.7 .. what error are you having @Sokhrat Sikar

Comment: I don't have any errors.. I have updated the question again and you can see the code...

Comment: assign $url to any image url, it is working fine and returning 200 status

Comment: check the url you are giving , and see if it is accessible from browser

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but i think you have the same problem i have. The problem is the httpS requets. In some way it doesn't work in xampp for windows, i remove the S and it works fine for me