# Using curl in XAMPP local enviroment not running

Tags: php, xampp

I have got quite a strange issue that is only occurring on my local XAMPP install. I have a script to extract data from a page using curl to open it as googlebot then using `str_get_html()` from simple_html_dom to extract DOM elements.

I am getting the following error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\facebook.php on line 49`

Top part of my function here (this function is very long so not going to post it all, will only post to the error):

```
function get_facebook_data($link)
{
    $username    = "";
    $title       = "";
    $location    = "";
    $email       = "";
    $description = "";
    $userAgent   = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
    $url         = get_facebook_page($link);
// THE ABOVE VARIABLE IS A VALID URL IF I ECHO IT WILL GIVE: http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Pencil-Test/179417698765073?id=179417698765073&sk=info BEFORE GIVING THE ERROR
    $ch          = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    $html     = curl_exec($ch);
    $cache    = $html;
    $html2    = str_get_html($cache);
    $data     = $html2->find("span.uiButtonText");
//THE LINE ABOVE IS THROWING THE ERROR
```

My script works fine in an online enviroment which makes me believe it is an xampp issue, by the looks of things something wrong with curl running locally. I have got `curl` enabled in xampp and it is showing as enabled in phpinfo(); Could it be something to do with my firewall perhaps?

Any help greatly appreciated,
Simon

## edit:

100% it is that curl is not running locally, changed title from: find() on a non-object in XAMPP using curl and simple_html_dom

Comment: I know what the error means, that is not my problem at all. I know the variable is not being defined by the looks of things it is because curl is not running correctly. But curl is working fine from the same function online.

Comment: What is `str_get_html()` ? Also, what does `var_dump($html);` say ?

Comment: `strl_get_html()` is here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm it creates a DOM object from a string. It is a function inside simple_html_dom and just checking var_dump now

Comment: var_dump for $html is `boolean false`

Comment: You can see the script working online here: http://simonstaton.co.uk/facebook.php just enter a keyword without a space (fixing this bug once I get this issue out the way)

Comment: Looks like you curl query failed. My just failed too.

Comment: Yeah was thinking the same, looks like an issue with xamp and windows. I have got curl enabled and have tried setting a port `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);` then enabling it in my firewall but no luck. Even disabling the windows firewall throws this same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768098/xampp-1-7-7-in-windows-7-returns-nothing-using-curl found this post just testing it out now to see

Comment: `Took 0.343 seconds to send a request to https://www.facebook.com/pages/County-of-Maui/150618851661152?id=150618851661152&sk=info` curl is working, just not grabbing the data