# curl is enabled but not getting any result in xampp 3.2.1

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to keep sendgrid API into My custom website. see this [link](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/php.html#-Using-PHP-with-cURL)

Now I am trying to get all Recipient Lists on my account for this one I installed xampp 3.2.1 version and curl is enabled I checked through `phpinfo()` function but I am not getting any result and this same code is working fine in my main 1and1 server but not getting in xampp localhost

```
 <?php
  $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/get.json';
  $user = 'x';
  $pass = 'y';

 $params = array(
   'api_user'  => $user,
   'api_key'   => $pass,
  );
 $request =  $url;


 $session = curl_init($request);

 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


 $response = curl_exec($session);
 curl_close($session);


 print_r($response);
  ?>
```

Comment: typcially you would post code so others can determine what the issues might be

Comment: what is your PHP version

Comment: My php version is 5.5.27 and curl version is 7.43.1

Comment: The above same code is getting results and  working fine in my main web server 1and1 but not getting in xampp localhost

Comment: see this same problem to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916462/using-curl-in-xampp-local-enviroment-not-running

Answer (score 3):

Wow finally I got solution for this one. I added single line of code into my project code.

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

below this code line

```
$session = curl_init($request);
```

please refer this link :

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score 0):

I tried signing up to test for myself but it wouldn't let me past the verification stage. With most curl calls to https I include the following - which may help.

```
$cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem'; 
/* You can download cacert.pem from the interwebs easily. Change the path to suit own environment */
if( parse_url( $request,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

Setup the openssl.cafile and openssl.capath in your php.ini and restart apache

Peer verification will be true by default, once the above values are set then the verification will pass. You can turn off this verification by setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER as false